# Color Dialog Displays behind browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, colordialog

I created a ASP.NET Web Forms Application and when I click on my button to display the color dialog it works correctly on first click.  Subsequent clicks the dialog box displays behind the browser. I noticed from some posts people had placed a color dialog on their form.  I'm not sure why, but the color dialog is no where in my toolbox. Looking forward to the answer to see my ID-10-T mistake.  Thanks!

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
        colorDialog.AnyColor = true;
        colorDialog.AllowFullOpen = false;

        if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string str = null;
            str = colorDialog.Color.Name;

            if (str.Substring(0, 2) == "ff")
            {
                str = "#" + str.Substring(2);
            }

            //MessageBox.Show(str);
            lblTo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);
            lblFrom.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);
            lblDate.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);
            lblTime.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);

            pnlKudos.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);
            pnlKudos.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);
            txtButWait.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(str);

            string sTemp = "border: 0px #fff solid;";
            txtExtra.Attributes["style"] = sTemp;
            sTemp = "border-bottom: 1px " + str + " solid;";
            txtExtra.Attributes["style"] = sTemp;
            sTemp = "background-color: " + str;
            divKudos.Attributes["style"] = sTemp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried (show your code!) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!  Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Here's the code for the click event

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the dialog box *on the server*.

It appears to work when you run the code from Visual Studio, but that's only because the server and the client happen to be the same machine in that instance.

As soon as you deploy your code to a real server, the code will stop working. If you're lucky, you'll get an exception telling you that you cannot show a dialog box from a non-interactive process. If not, your code will hang waiting for someone to log in to the server and close the dialog box.

You need to use a client-side colour picker. Google has lots of examples - eg:

- http://jscolor.com/
- http://colpick.com/plugin
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp